# Period of inactivity, run a script

Tags: autoit

What I am looking to do is to run a .exe ONLY when a user goes inactive .  When the screen becomes active again, the script should start up again.

Logic:

```
While True:
     Is the user active:          
     NO-> Is the .exe running -> Yes: Do nothing  No: run the Program
     YES -> Close the .exe
```

Any suggestions on how I can program this using Auto It

Edit:

Inactivity: no user activity (either moving the mouse or otherwise)
Run the program:  This is a custom .exe file, that will be kept in the same folder.

This is for a Windows box, and not a Linux machine

Comment: Define "active" for this purpose? What does this program you want to run do? Is hooking into the screensaver useful for this?

Comment: A custom .exe file, i'll edit the question

Comment: How do you measure active is the important question. Could perhaps look at active login sessions via `who` or similar.

Comment: Was thinking about looking for keystrokes.  Have you seen being pressed?

Comment: When you rename the .exe to .scr you can use it as a screensaver. (Of course there is a little more to it, but if it's a custom .exe the changes should be trivial.)

Comment: I have to imagine that Windows applications can detect when the screensaver/power save/idle timer/etc. triggers and respond to that. AutoIt/autohotkey can probably do this too I imagine.

Comment: That's what i'm hoping for.  I've got the logic, but cannot get only a single .exe to run!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [_Timer_GetIdleTime()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Timer_GetIdleTime.htm) is exactly what you need.
> Returns the number
>   of ticks since last user activity (i.e. KYBD/Mouse)

Example usage:

```
#include <Timers.au3>

$InactivityTrigger = 5*1000 ;inactive for 5 seconds
$myExe = "calc.exe"
$PID = 0

While True

    $InactiveFor = _Timer_GetIdleTime()

    If $InactiveFor >= $InactivityTrigger And Not $PID Then

        $PID = Run($myExe)
        ConsoleWrite("started" & @CRLF)

    ElseIf $InactiveFor < $InactivityTrigger And $PID Then

        ProcessClose($PID)
        $PID = 0
        ConsoleWrite("stopped" & @CRLF)

    EndIf

    If Not $PID And Not IsFloat($InactiveFor/10) Then ToolTip("Inactive for: " & Round($InactiveFor/1000) & " seconds." & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
                   "Will run exe in " & Round( ($InactivityTrigger-$InactiveFor)/1000 ) & " seconds." )

Wend
```